# Excel Macro that edits pre-existing word template, saves & attaches to new email - Shows Attachment as "Download Failed"

Tags: excel, vba, email, ms-word

I seem to have all the leading steps for my macro working, the pre-set template is edited, updated and saved within the source folder ready for attachement. As the Email opens and attaches the document it shows as "download failed" each time.

I can get the below code to work using direct paths, however the intention is for the document to be circulated to team mates to use on their local drive. I would like this to run with everything it needs from the source folder the user chooses to save in.

```
Sub ReplaceText4()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim FileName As String
Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path

'Cell that holds the File Name.

FileName = Range("C34")

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = False

'Location of Template file.

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\Test\HSP blank ber.docx")

'What to replace within template document.

With wDoc
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<DATE>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<CLAIMNUMBER>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C34")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<SURNAME>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C38")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<POSTCODE>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C40")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<GCNUMBER>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C28")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<snum>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C42")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<MAKE>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C30")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<MODEL>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C32")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<AGE>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C36")

    .SaveAs2 FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileName, _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    wApp.ActiveDocument.Close
    wApp.Quit
    Set wApp = Nothing
End With

'Attach Word Doc to email.

 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
 Dim OutApp As Object
 
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments


'Location of saved/edited word doc.

 myAttachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileName, olByValue, 1, "HSP-BER"

 myItem.Display

End Sub
```

I have tried file paths from one drive as well as using ActiveWorkbook.Path with no progress. Changing the save file from word to pdf has no effect either. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `ThisWorkbook.Path` a local drive, or a HTTP path?

Comment: It's a local drive, I currently have the excel sheet stored in documents on C drive

Comment: Sometimes when you open a document from a local drive, if that location is synced to OneDrive/SharePoint, it will instead open from the HTTP path - that's not the case here?